# Return connection to knex db pool

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, connection-pooling, knex.js

I'm using knex version 3.10.10, in my node app, connecting to MySQL DB.
My configuration of knex in the app is using the pool option configuration.

1) Is there a need to EXPLICITLY return a connection to the pool after I fired a query? If yes - how

2) Is there a need to EXPLICITLY perform a check on a pool's connection, before firing the query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no need to do either.

Knex handles a connection pool for you. You can adjust the pool size if you need to by using the setting: `pool: { min: 0, max: 7 }` within your connection setup, and the documentation also includes a link to the library that Knex uses for pool handling if you care about the gory details.

The knex documentation has a little info on this here: [link](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-pooling)

Each connection will be used by Knex for the duration of a query or a transaction, then released back to the pool.

BUT, if you implement transactions (i.e. multiple SQL statements to be saved or cancelled as a unit) without using Promises, then you will need to explicitly commit/rollback the transaction to properly complete the transaction, which will also release the connection back to the pool when the transaction is complete. (see more on Knex Transactions: [here](http://knexjs.org/#Transactions)).

Comment: your explanation is good.i am using knex connection without transaction.I just put `require `knex and call `query.then` .do i  need to explicitly close the connection?

Comment: No, knex does this by itself.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such info in the documentation but based on the [source](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/util/make-knex.js#L73) [code](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/client.js#L275) you can access `knex` pool like this

```
const knex = require('knex')(config);
const pool = knex.client.pool;
console.log(pool);
```

`knex` uses [tarn](https://github.com/Vincit/tarn.js) pool under the hood, so you can check out it's methods there.

P.S. I don't know where did you get that `knex` version (3 point something) but the current version of it on this answer moment is `0.14.4`